# C# WebServices Lists.GetCollection returns Status HTTP 404: Not Found on a subpage

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, http-status-code-404

**UPDATE**: 
A little update when I try to get the collection from the following url:
**lista.Url = @"http://website/Page1/Page2/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";**
I get the collection and I can see the lists.
the remainder : **WebReferenceTest/Lists/ListTest/** has been created by my, i.e. the WebReferenceTest. Perhaps I messed up something with rights to that page, etc.
Maybe this will shed some light on the problem.

Hi, 
   I'm new to the Web Services, 
I've been trying to do a simple application to get and add items to a specific list stored on Sharepoint server via AddWebReference. 
I've been following several threads/howtos/articles on that matter but I've reached a point where I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, or the server has to have some specific settings.
I'm using Visual Studio 2005.

The code is as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            listTest.Lists lista = new listTest.Lists();
            lista.Url = @"http://website/Page1/Page2/WebReferenceTest/Lists/ListTest/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
            lista.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;             

            System.Xml.XmlNode activeItemData = lista.GetListCollection();

            foreach (System.Xml.XmlNode listItem in activeItemData)
            { 
               textBox1.AppendText(listItem.OuterXml + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Detail.InnerText);
        }
    }

}
```

When I run this code as it is I'll get "HTTP 404: Not Found", but when I'll comment the changed URL reverting to the basic address then I get a collection of lists on the main page, or something like that.

I can access that page in question in web browser, but in VS2005 I'll get the 404 error.

So the question is is it me doing something awkward or the server requires additional configuration. I have no access to it, but I guess I can get it done by someone else.

PS: The app.config looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="WindowsApplication2.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <WindowsApplication2.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="WindowsApplication2_listTest_Lists" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://website/_vti_bin/lists.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsApplication2.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Thank you for any input.
Pawel

Comment: Make sure you have the same permissions over the sub site. Also, I assume both are under the same domain localhost on same port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call function by using `@"http://website/Page1/Page2/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` It will take internally path upto `@"http://website/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` only.

So always give path upto your Site Or RootSiteCollection.

Just modify your code as below:

```
lista.Url = @"http://website/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
```

You may get all function available by calling `@"http://website/Page1/Page2/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` url in browser. But click Service Description link than you will see what exactly I want to convey you. It will give you same 404 error. Once you get that try to remove `'Page1/Page2'` and again press enter.

Comment: Hi thank you very much, it helped. I simply used wrong page to look for my list in the lista.url property. Thanks again for a quick answer.